# Apache WebDav Configuration

Tags: apache, webdav, apache2.2

I am trying to configure WebDav on Apache 2.2 on FreeBSD.
Apache is running fine, serving a lot of stuff.

All the dav modules seem to be included in LoadModules command.
This Virtual Host works fine.

When i visit www.mysite.com/admin/ i get the directory listing. Nothing else. I want to be able to read/write etc.

```
<VirtualHost 10.11.11.103:8180>
    ...
    config to server my site
    ...
    #enable webdav
    DavLockDB "/var/log/www/DavLock"
    Alias /admin/ /home/testing/pdf/
    <Directory "/home/testing/pdf/">
        Dav On
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
            Allow from All
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>

    # fixes a problem with several clients - redirects for folders with DAV methods.
    BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-careful
    BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: IS A DIRECTORY LISTING ALL I SHOULD EXPECT? DO I NEED A WEBDAV CLIENT FOR ANYTHING MORE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes u need some kind of webdav client so u can actualy see if it works. You can try bitkinex client.